# Sublime Text 3: Put LaTeX build files in subdirectory

Tags: latex, sublime-text-3, pdflatex

When I create a PDF from my .tex file, a lot of extra files are generated, with extensions such as .aux, .syntex.gz, etc. Is it possible to put these files in a subdirectory, and still have the compiler know where they are?

Comment: Not easily, no, because `pdflatex` will look for them in the same directory, and has no way to set a different aux directory (unlike in [MikTeX, apparently](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/how-can-i-put-aux-files-in-separate-folder-using-a-command-inside-texworks)). You could edit the LaTeXTools scripts to move the files around temporarily, but it would be overwritten every time the package upgrades.